# Way too high non-paged pool

Tags: memory-leaks

I'm having trouble fixing my high non-paged pool, I really have no idea what I'm doing so if anyone knows how to fix this it would make my day.

[image]

It is starting to annoy me big time, I can't multitask because I don't have enough RAM all the time.

[image]

EDIT:
Just tried a different command and found out it's excsd.sys.

puu.sh/iaZi4/f603ab7e51.png

Do I just update it in order to fix this problem?

EDIT:
I updated the driver, it seems to have worked but I'll keep everyone up to date if anything changes.

Download the latest version [here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds035460)

Comment: Its helpful if you ask all questions, in the actual question, and not in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I fixed it with updating the driver and here is what I did step by step:

1. Installed WDK (Windows Driver Kit)
2. Booted up poolmon.exe
3. Sorted it to Nonp and sorted bytes to show highest
4. Looked at which tag was using the most bytes (in my case ECMC)
5. Booted up Command Prompt
6. Typed "cd drivers", then typed "findstr /l /m ECMC *.sys"  which gave me the name of the driver that was leaking
7. I updated the driver in this case [here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds035460)

I hope this helped someone experiencing a similar or the same problem.